# Any known plugins for master admin login to edit all on front end?

Tags: admin, login

Have a theme that accepts posts on the front end by users and gives them a front end dashboard too to edit...

I was wondering if there are any known plug-ins for the admin to edit all as if they were logged in as a user?

Basically a master login revealing the users dashboard info./options to edit on their behalf as admin master login?

Shawn

Comment: the same way you created the front end dashboard you can create One for the admin.

Answer (score 1):

[Front-End editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) by Scribu, could be resolve your problem. As admin , you can edit everithing in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

I used Front End editor extensively for a few months and it works well. Don't be surprised if it makes your home page look a little weird when you're logged in.

For example on my site, it changed my tagline font to italics and smaller size but not a big deal. If you're not logged in, you (and visitors) will see your "regular" home page.